# Strange behaviour - different results in phpMyAdmin and VS 2017 for same SQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I know there are some posts on here about strange behaviours between phpMyAdmin and PHP, but I have a really odd situation when using the MySQL connector in VB.Net(VS 2017)

Using MySQLData.dll version = 6.10.6.0

```
Database server
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 5.6.43 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Web server
cpsrvd 11.78.0.38
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.2.7
phpMyAdmin
Version information: 4.8.3
```

When executing the SQL in phpMyAdmin, I get the correct answer in that it returns two rows. However, in VB.Net it only returns one row. I'm guessing this might be something to do with MySQL.Data.dll?

I run the code in debug, with a breakpoint just after it's created the SQL, then I copy and paste this into MyAdmin.

```vb
            Dim tblDataTable As New DataTable
            Dim sql As String = "" 
            sql = "
select 
    s.id, 
    s.firstname, 
    s.surname, 
    s.dob, 
    s.ref, 
    s.fb, 
    s.status, 
    r.type, 
    r.rate, 
    r.perweek, 
    r.peryear, 
    r.prac, 
    r.sused, 
    r.left,
    h.hep
from 
    tbl_s as s 
    left join tbl_ssr as r 
    on s.id = r.stid
    left join tbl_h as h 
    on s.hei = h.code
where 
    s.id = @currentid
"
'This has been tried with both a parameter and a hard coded value, both with the same erroneous results.
            Debug.Print(sql)
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentid", currentID)
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                conn.Open()
            End If
            tblDataTable = New DataTable
            Using dataRead As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                tblDataTable.Load(dataRead) 
            End Using
            Debug.Print(tblDataTable.Rows.Count.ToString + "rows")
            Dim rv As frmReportViewer = generateTimeSheets(tblDataTable)
            rv.Name = "Timesheet"
            rv.Text = "Timesheet"
            rv.MdiParent = MDIParent1
            rv.Show()
```

The SQL should return 2 rows, but tblDataTable only has 1 row in it.

Just to clarify... the Vb.Net code pulls out *one* of the correct records, just not both of them.

Comment: What i am struggling is s.id = @currentid where do you set this session variable? What are the s.id's for both rows?

Comment: I'm a bit lost by your questions... @currentid  is set 3 lines below the line you're querying (and the comment about hard coding it too) ... On both rows?, the s.id is the same... its a relational database - s is core table with one record (s.id) which left joins on tbl_ssr which has two records for this particular s.id, therefore there should be 2 rows returned in both vb.net and phpMyAdmin. Actual s.id seems irrelevant in this question.

Comment: @nbk : In this case it isn't a session variable, but an SQL parameter. He sets it at this line: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentid", currentID)`

Comment: Further analysis shows it's ignoring the first row of the two it should be returning... if that helps any...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the VB.Net connector is a little picky over what you ask it to do. Tried various different `JOIN` functions and orders, still returned only 1 row in VB.

Ended up re-ordering the query, looking at what I wanted to retrieve and where it all came from.

Still doesn't answer *why* the same SQL in VB.Net returned only 1 row whereas phpMyAdmin returned 2, but at least it got it working.

Final working SQL is:

```vb
select 
    r.sid, 
    s.firstname, 
    s.surname, 
    s.dob, 
    s.ref, 
    s.fb, 
    s.status, 
    s.hep,
    r.type, 
    r.rate, 
    r.perweek, 
    r.peryear, 
    r.prac, 
    r.sused, 
    r.left
from 
    tbl_ssr as r  
    join tbl_s as s on r.sd = s.id

where 
    r.sid = @currentid
```